# passing the content of a file to an argument of jar file

Tags: shell, jar

I have to run a jar file from linux command line and I don't have access to its code.
One of the argument -pep is a string.
Am I able to pass to -pep argument the content of a file?

```
java -jar pepquery-1.3.jar -pep NAEQYKDQADK -ms ../../Documents/Roucou/proteogenomic/Exp1_786O_nox_scr.mgf -db ../../Documents/example.fasta -c 1 -cpu 12 -t 1 -itol 0.02 -maxCharge 2 -tol 5 -o ../../Documents -m 1
```

Instead of passing the string NAEQYKDQADK into -pep, I want it reads it from a text file which contains just that string.
Its path is /home/mariano/Documents/peptide.txt.
Something like:

```
java -jar pepquery-1.3.jar -pep /home/mariano/Documents/peptide.txt -ms ../../Documents/Roucou/proteogenomic/Exp1_786O_nox_scr.mgf -db ../../Documents/example.fasta -c 1 -cpu 12 -t 1 -itol 0.02 -maxCharge 2 -tol 5 -o ../../Documents -m 1
```

which obviously does not work.

Comment: `-pep "$(cat yourfile.txt)"`?

Comment: no that does not work